# RGBDSLAM with ROS electric on Linux Mint 12

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosdep, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was trying to install rgdbslam stack on Linux Mint 12, I recive this information:

```
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/majkel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111202-133828                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
['rgbdslam']                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages rgbdslam.  This may take a few seconds.                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 865, in main
    self.rosdep_check_result = self.check_rosdep(buildable_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 295, in check_rosdep
    r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.detect_os()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 554, in detect_os
    self._os_version = os_class.get_version()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 133, in get_version
    return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()]
KeyError: '12'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 865, in main
    self.rosdep_check_result = self.check_rosdep(buildable_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 295, in check_rosdep
    r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.detect_os()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 554, in detect_os
    self._os_version = os_class.get_version()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 133, in get_version
    return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()]
KeyError: '12'
```

Next step, I edited /opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py and added my OS  version

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mint_detector = roslib.os_detect.Mint()
    self.version_map = {'12':'11.10',
                 '11':'11.04',
                        '10':'10.10',
                        '9':'10.04',
                        '8':'9.10', 
                        '7':'9.04',
                        '6':'8.10',
                        '5':'8.04'}
```

... Now I have new information

```
majkel@laptop-mk /opt/ros/electric/stacks $ rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/majkel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111202-135209                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
['rgbdslam']                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .                          
No installers found for rosdep [boost], OS version [11.10].  Rule:
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.40-all-dev']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}, 'oneiric': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.46-all-dev']}}}
}    }}

No installers found for rosdep [opencv2.3], OS version [11.10].  Rule:
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~natty']}}, 'oneiric': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~oneiric']}}}
}}}

No installers found for rosdep [eigen], OS version [11.10].  Rule:
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~natty']}}, 'oneiric': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev']}}}
}}}

No installers found for rosdep [glut], OS version [11.10].  Rule:
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libglut3-dev']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libglut3-dev']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libglut3-dev']}}, 'oneiric': {'apt': {'packages': ['freeglut3-dev']}}}
}}}

Failed to find rosdep eigen for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep glut for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep boost for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed
```

Any ideas? How to install this stack? Was It a good step I edited this file? I have installed all of this packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12185/rgbdslam-with-ros-electric-on-linux-mint-12/) by [garoth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1480/garoth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My new code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mint_detector = roslib.os_detect.Mint()
    self.version_map = {'12':'oneric',
                        '11':'11.04',
                        '10':'10.10',
                        '9':'10.04',
                        '8':'9.10',
                        '7':'9.04',
                        '6':'8.10',
                        '5':'8.04'}
```

Before I add a ticket, I would say that the compiler jumps to the next step, but turned the information that can't find some packages.

```
...
Failed to find rosdep eigen for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep glut for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep boost for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'eigen', u'glut', u'boost', u'opencv2.3'] could not be resolved
Failed to find rosdep eigen for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep glut for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep boost for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
...
```

... but generaly it works, so it is some kind of solution. Unfortunetly there is another problem with grahp_manager.cpp file. I met this problem both Unbuntu and Linux Mint. It is global bug I think, but mayby it is http://answers.ros.org/question/2857/rgbdslam-compile-errors.

---

Originally posted by [garoth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1480/garoth/) with karma: 96 on 2011-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the right file to patch.  From looking at the rule, it looks like you should use the code name not the version.  Likely all of the version maps should be switched.  A patch would be greatly appreciated in trac. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=rosdep&type=defect&&rosdep

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3